# Clear Asp.net MVC cache via URL using Misc/ClearCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

There is a sort of "trick" that I've seen around more than once, in order to clear the cache for an MVC app by calling a specific url similar to

http://somewebsite.com/Misc/ClearCache

I used it a couple of times, but honestly I didn't understand exactly how it works and I haven't found any documentation or post about it.

Is there anyone that could explain it a bit, possibly with some related documentation?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking you could use this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532195/5224021, in an ajax request and load it into an iframe

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my comment, no Ajax needed.

Here would be your JQuery:

```
$("#clearCache").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).disabled) {
        $('<iframe id="cacheCleared" src="../../Misc/ClearCache"></iframe>').appendTo('body').hide();
    }
});
```

Then in your Misc Controller you would have:

```
public ActionResult ClearCache()
{
    foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in   HttpContext.Cache)
    {
        HttpContext.Cache.Remove((entry.Key).ToString());
    }

    return View();
}
```

Once you append your `iframe`, it will attempt to load the content from that source. When it tries to load that source, it will hit your `ClearCache` in your controller and should clear everything.

**EDIT:**
Add this before you `return View();` if you want to avoid building a view for it.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using some plugin or 3rd party library for that. But it is as simple as :

1. write a web method to clearcache like:

   ```
   public void Clearcache() 
   { 
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); 
   }
   ```
2. Call method from browser with like controller/actionname :http://somewebsite.com/Controller/ClearCache

If cache is 3rd party you can delete as required in same method